Inkscape causes xfce4-session segfault when exited or killed
Today I have encountered weird behaviour of my computer running Debian 12 with xfce4 and SID repositories added (Which I hate, because it creates ton of bugs everywhere, but some software was not actualised in stable repositories for years and I need it for my work)
When I have closed Inkscape, I have been immediately logged off. After log in again, Inkscape stared automatically. I have closed it and I was logged of again. Ok, I won't negotiate with terrorists, I have found process number and send SIGKILL to it. Log off again. Then I have checked dmesg and found bunch of xfce4-session segfaults:
[ 3979.941201] xfce4-session[9902]: segfault at 10000 ip 000055cc7441c379 sp 00007fffc4a1c8c0 error 4 in xfce4-session[55cc74407000+1b000] likely on CPU 2 (core 0, socket 0)
[ 3979.941214] Code: e8 9c b7 fe ff 48 89 c3 48 85 c0 74 c0 e8 af 5b ff ff 49 89 c6 eb 13 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 48 8b 5b 08 48 85 db 74 a3 <48> 8b 3b 4c 89 f6 e8 fc b1 fe ff 48 89 c7 48 89 c5 e8 f1 6d ff ff
[ 3983.091870] rfkill: input handler disabled
[ 3984.124280] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
[ 3989.623600] rfkill: input handler enabled
[ 3992.704956] traps: light-locker[12842] trap int3 ip:7f4ca491fef7 sp:7ffe6731cf80 error:0 in libglib-2.0.so.0.8200.2[7f4ca48d9000+9f000]
[ 3993.769069] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
[ 3993.861428] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
[ 3993.862599] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
[ 4168.926075] xfce4-session[12530]: segfault at 10000 ip 0000558ca8d78379 sp 00007fffbed6bfd0 error 4 in xfce4-session[558ca8d63000+1b000] likely on CPU 1 (core 1, socket 0)
[ 4168.926089] Code: e8 9c b7 fe ff 48 89 c3 48 85 c0 74 c0 e8 af 5b ff ff 49 89 c6 eb 13 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 48 8b 5b 08 48 85 db 74 a3 <48> 8b 3b 4c 89 f6 e8 fc b1 fe ff 48 89 c7 48 89 c5 e8 f1 6d ff ff
[ 4172.180982] rfkill: input handler disabled
[ 4172.228625] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
[ 4178.253921] rfkill: input handler enabled
[ 4181.613760] traps: light-locker[15473] trap int3 ip:7fe9d0c12ef7 sp:7ffe5cfa4cb0 error:0 in libglib-2.0.so.0.8200.2[7fe9d0bcc000+9f000]
[ 4182.637800] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
[ 4182.709922] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
[ 4182.712671] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7

Do you have any idea what's going on here? I have been using this system for quite a while without modification and Inkscape always worked as fine.
